# What happens if an electric charge is run through a resistor on both ends?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics

For example, if 2 wires connected in parallel have a resistor put between them, how would you calculate the effective resistance of this circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ideally, no current flow over the resistor

Assuming that the wires are perfect conductors they're joined, then both wires have the same potential (voltage) throughout.  So, you have zero voltage drop over the resistor, so no current would flow over it.

Then, the net resistance of the overall circuit's zero because any current that wants to flow through the circuit will just flow down one of the wires without resistance.

#### Some real-world corrections

In real life, wires have some resistance, even when it's small.  In this case, you'd model each wire as two resistors in series, with each wire's middle junction connected to the other wire's middle junction by the resistor.  Then, you'd calculate currents based on this model.

In this model, you may find some current flowing through the center resistor if the wires' resistances aren't balanced.  It'd likely be small, but non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Take x on a junction and y on the other junction then apply Kirchhoff's loop law on the two loops or just use nodal analysis

Hope it helps